# How to change login background in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, login-screen

How do I change the login background in Windows XP?

Comment: Are you using the welcome screen or the dialog with Username and Password fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To Add A Windows XP Logon Wallpaper**

1. Navigate to: `HKEY USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop`
2. Double click the wallpaper value, and type in the full path of your image and the filename.
3. To tile the image set "TileWallPaper" to 1
4. To Stretch the wallpaper set "WallPaperStyle" to 2
5. Close the registry editor and the changes will take place when you Log off.

[(Source)](http://www.updatexp.com/tip12.html)

Comment: It didn't work for me...